# iMessage: Receiving at two devices

Tags: iphone, messages

I got a new iPhone 4S, but I had upgraded my old iPhone 4 to iOS 5. On Wi-Fi, I get iMessages on both the phones. I want to receive them only on my 4S and not the 4.

Answer (score 2):

Under `Settings > Messages > Receive At`, remove your email address, you should then only receive the messages on your iPhone 4S.

You can also, set up a new Apple ID for your brother. He should then be able to receive iMessage on both his phone number and his email address.